# Finding the index of the minimum value of a column and arranging into a list in numerical order by column element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following matrix:

```
matrix = np.random.randn(10,10)
```

I have found the index of the minimum values in each column:

```
minimum_values = np.min(matrix, axis = 0)
index_of_minimum = np.where(matrix == minimum_values)
print(index_of_minimum)
```

The code above outputs the following:

```
(array([1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9], dtype=int64), array([9, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 0, 3, 6, 8], dtype=int64))
```

Is there a way to arrange `[9, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 0, 3, 6, 8]` to a list, from 0 to 9, with the associated minimum indexes (`[1, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9]`) per column?

Comment: Are you asking if you can convert that result to a list of tuples, i.e., `[(1, 9), (3, 1), (3, 5), ...]`?

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for argsort? could you try `[*map(lambda x: x[np.argsort(index_of_minimum[1])],index_of_minimum)]` ?